# Explode tab delimited text from textarea to array ready to for insert statement

Tags: php, html, textarea, explode

I've created a textarea so users can insert class codes associated to a particular module. The user will copy from excel and paste into a html textarea. for example:

[image]

When pasted in the textarea the above is separated by tabs. In php how would i convert each row into a seperate array? e.g. Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

```
array(1)
(
    [0] => "moduleA"
    [1] => "class1"
)
array(2)
(
    [0] => "moduleA"
    [1] => "class2"
)
array(3)
(
    [0] => "moduleA"
    [1] => "class3"
)
```

Comment: If you are going to split on newline characters first, then I recommend the `\R` metacharacter in regex to match all newline sequences.

Answer (score 0):

From my experiences, a new row in textarea (by default) is a `\n`. You can implode/explode (depends on what you want) with `\n` for every row. e.g `explode("\n", $data);`

Comment: In 2022, when your advice is use `explode("\n")`, you can be sure that the question is a duplicate and can be safely closed.  If you don't like the links that I have closed with, leave a comment with a better one and I'll add it to the list.

Comment: i think the main of his concern is not that `explode` but the`\n`. He (maybe) doesn't know that `\n` is there or textarea translate the new row as `\n` without debug it.